# PhantomJS can't render italic and bold, however Chrome can

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs, fabricjs

[image]

I rendered a normal SVG to PDF via phantomJS (left side),
but the result is different from the SVG displayed in Chrome.

I used a font called 'AlexBrush', which is a true-type font and has only regular style, I guess the bold and italic result is just "SIMULATED" by chrome?

How do I make phantomJS render correctly like chrome does?

This is part of my test SVG, which is generated by fabricJS:

```
<g transform="translate(509.4 276.56) scale(3.89 3.89)">
    <text font-family="AbrilFatface" font-size="42" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
        <tspan x="-131.5" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">i</tspan>
        <tspan x="-122.01" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
        <tspan x="-109.53" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
        <tspan x="-101.22" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">i</tspan>
        <tspan x="-91.73" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">s</tspan>
        <tspan x="-76.65" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
        <tspan x="-68.33" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">a</tspan>
        <tspan x="-51.03" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
        <tspan x="-42.71" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">l</tspan>
        <tspan x="-32.51" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">a</tspan>
        <tspan x="-15.2" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">z</tspan>
        <tspan x="1.01" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">y</tspan>
        <tspan x="16.55" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
        <tspan x="24.87" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">f</tspan>
        <tspan x="35.03" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">o</tspan>
        <tspan x="46.83" y="13.23" font-family="AlexBrush" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">x</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

---

Update: so this "SIMULATED" style is called "FAUX" bold.
However, I still don't know how to make phantomJS do the same as chrome does.

http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

Comment: Could you post a simple snippet with the fabricjs canvas, a text in your font and a toSVG button?

Comment: YABIP = Yet another bug in PhantomJS. PhantomJS does something different than what Chrome does. If you would render the screen as PNG or JPG in PhantomJS it would probably render it correctly.